# OSX command line tool works correctly while debugging in Xcode but fails to load a .dylib when run externally

Tags: xcode, macos, executable, dynamic-linking

I'm using Xcode to build a command line tool which depends on an external .dylib file.  Normally, if this were a packaged application, I would include the .dylib as an embedded framework and include it in "Link Binary with Libraries".

Instead, I am only using "Link Binary with Libraries".  I link 9 libraries, and when starting from finder, the application successfully finds 8 of them.  But, 1 cannot be found, and I'm not sure why.

I feel that part of the confusion is in the way I'm setting the "Library Search Paths" and "Framework Search Paths".  It is my understanding that the entries in these fields are relative to the location of the Xcode Project file.  Yet, I not sure how to use these fields to indicate the location of libraries relative to the binaries' final location.

I'm not sure why it works correctly within Xcode in debug mode, but when I go out to the file on disk and run it outside of Xcode it fails to find the library.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libzmq.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-aujthxhimuknufcrjzfhdwchezas/Build/Products/Debug/ProjectName
  Reason: image not found
```

I have added "./" and the recursive option to debug / release in both "Framework Search Paths" and "Library Search Paths".  The file "libzmq.3.dylib" is in the same directory as the final executable.

Comment: Are you setting the `runpath` of the executable in your build settings?  Generally if it works in debug and not release, it would mean the settings are different for debug/release mode.

Comment: Also framework search path and library search path are link-time settings, not runtime settings.  You probably want to added `@loader_path` to the `runpath`.

Comment: Hmm, OK.  I just updated my original post because I had mistakenly said I was having trouble with debug / release, but I intended to say I am having trouble between debugging within XCode and running the built version outside of XCode (but still in the debug folder).

Comment: I did check, and runpath has no value

Comment: Well if you set that correctly and all dylibs are using `@rpath` as their *install name* it should work fine.

Comment: I think my confusion is rooted in some basic concepts:  When the linker links these different source files together, does the linker include dynamic libraries at link time?  I had believed that dynamic libraries were needed at run time and only invoked if needed, or is this the function of the "optional" flag?  Also, how do I determine the install name of a dylib?

Comment: The *optional* setting will *weak link* the library; something I've never done myself.  You can see the install_name of the libraries using `install_name_tool`.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several things wrong here, so it might be good to take a step back and see where things might've gotten confused.

> 1. Copy all required .dylibs to your project directory
> 2. Remove added **Framework Search Paths**, (dylib's are not considered  "frameworks")
> 3. **Library Search Paths** should really be the only place you need to look

### Build Settings

Library Search Paths is where the compiler looks for your dylibs that will be linked to your app:

```
$(inherited)
"$(SRCROOT)/path/to/dylib"
```

I usually find that these two paths work just fine. The top one searches your main project directory, and the second one searches in a /path/ below the source root.

[image]

### Build Phases

[image]

Build Phases determines the specifics for file, libraries, etc. that are part of your project, such as linking the `dylib` using "**Link Binary With Libraries**" and adding a "**Copy Files Phase**".

The linking is what essentially makes the connection between your executable and the library (there are several ways to link a library, this is just one). The copy phase allows you to choose where the dylib should be copied and located for your executable to use after it's built (I often copy them to the destination of the executable).

Regardless if your project is a command-line application, if not specifically copying required dylibs from the build phase don't count on your app linking to external libraries (unless it's standard); even so, relying on a library you don't provide could render the app useless if the path of a dylib changes, or gets removed. I would recommend when possible providing dylibs with the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to resolve the issue:
Under "Linking->Runpath Search Path", add: @loader_path.

See the attached image bellow:
[image]